# IPMItool sel command on PER610 does not provide detailed information

Tags: linux, ipmitool

```
ipmitool sel elist
```

on R610 output:

```
1 | 08/01/2011 | 23:18:11 | Event Logging Disabled SEL | Log area reset/cleared | Asserted
2 | Pre-Init Time-stamp   | Physical Security Intrusion | General Chassis intrusion | Asserted
3 | Pre-Init Time-stamp   | Physical Security Intrusion | General Chassis intrusion | Deasserted
4 | 01/31/2012 | 11:32:50 | Temperature #0x30 | Upper Critical going high
```

on R810 its:

```
Severity          : Normal
Date and Time     : System Boot
Description       : The chassis is closed while the power is On.
Event Data        : 0x80 0x02 0xff
```

I am concern about severity of message. I am developing a code which will send an email if the message is critical. But in the case of R610 there is no way to found severity of message.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to read the actual data from the SEL then you need to use the `ipmitool sel get` command and not the `ipmitool sel elist` command.

the `ipmitool sel get` command returns the detailed breakdown of the information in the event log for the item in question.

e.g. from one of my own systems:

```
machine:/ # ipmitool sel get 0x2c
SEL Record ID          : 002c
 Record Type           : 02
 Timestamp             : 02/13/2012 17:49:21
 Generator ID          : 0021
 EvM Revision          : 04
 Sensor Type           : Voltage
 Sensor Number         : 60
 Event Type            : Threshold
 Event Direction       : Assertion Event
 Event Data            : 02ffff
 Description           : Lower Critical going low
```

Comment: You can get this detail from ipmitool -vv sel list, it gives the same output. But my concern is severity of the message, like the event occur is Normal or Critical. If you see the output from R810, it does say severity is normal. Anyways thanks for your responce. If you know some more raw commands for ipmitool, please let me know.

Comment: If the sensor in question provides more than a simple 'assert/deassert', but instead provides criticality in the form of thresholds that may be exceeded in both directions, then you would see the criticality of the event being Upper, Lower. Chassis intrusion sensors are (typically) discrete, therefore they only trigger an assert/deassert.